# Phonegap Synchronization

Tags: json, cordova, phonegap-plugins, sqlite

I am starting to learn to do app in phonegap. I have been doing synchronization on phonegap using websql and backbone by following [example](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/06/employee-directory-is-now-available-on-the-app-store/)

But instead of using websql,

1. I want to grab data from local json file for offline usage and sync data from mysql server when online. Is is possible to synchronise and edit the json file that store in www folder?
2. or i would like to know how to sync with [phonegapsqlite plugin](https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can edit a ".json" file using phonegap.Instead you can create a txt file in www folder and keep the json there using JSON.stringify() once you synchronize from the mysql server.Then you can read the txt file using file reader with phonegap and convert the text to json using JSON.Parse().

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

hey you should use a java project having mysql as database,use rest services to send data in database in JSON form .you should make two projects .first project with phonegap and other one with java coding .make url to call rest services on java side and retr